# Getting error reading from 0xfefefefe when destructor is called

Tags: c++

I have made a c++ wrapper for an allegro bitmap. I create an AguiBitmap as a global variable for testing, then  later I say,

```
bitmap = AguiBitmap("somepath");
```

after allegro has been initialized.

However, when I close the application, it crashes in the bitmap's destructor. If I do al_destroy_bitmap(0); its fine, but there cant be anything wrong with my bitmap pointer because I use it to render.

```
AguiBitmap::~AguiBitmap()
{
        al_destroy_bitmap(nativeBitmapPtr); 
}

AguiBitmap::AguiBitmap()
{
    nativeBitmapPtr = 0;
    width = 0;
    height = 0;
}

AguiBitmap::AguiBitmap( char *filename )
{

    if(!filename)
    {
        nativeBitmapPtr = 0;
        return;
    }

    nativeBitmapPtr = al_load_bitmap(filename);

    if(nativeBitmapPtr)
    {

        width = al_get_bitmap_width(nativeBitmapPtr);
        height = al_get_bitmap_height(nativeBitmapPtr);
    }
    else
    {
        width = 0;
        height = 0;
    }
}

AguiBitmap::AguiBitmap( std::string filename )
{
    AguiBitmap((char*)filename.c_str());
}

ALLEGRO_BITMAP* AguiBitmap::getBitmap() const
{
    return nativeBitmapPtr;
}

int AguiBitmap::getWidth() const
{
    return width;
}

int AguiBitmap::getHeight() const
{
    return height;
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have not defined a copy constructor (**edit**: or copy-assignment operator).

```
bitmap = AguiBitmap("somepath");
```

That line constructs a temporary `AguiBitmap` which allocates the bitmap, then assigns to `bitmap` variable and the temporary is destroyed, releasing the bitmap. Therefore, any use of `bitmap` after this line is invalid!

**Edit**: specifically, when `bitmap` goes out of scope, the destructor is invoked for the 2nd object and the same bitmap is deleted again.

Comment: how should I make my copy constructor?

Comment: @Milo:  [A good introductory C++ book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c++-book-guide-and-list) will explain proper C++ memory management, object lifetimes, and issues related to implementing resource-owning containers.  Specifically, I'd recommend reading Herb Sutter's _Exceptional C++_.  Items 8-19 and 35-41 cover this subject in depth.

Comment: That line invokes the copy assignment operator, not the copy constructor.

Comment: How would I create my copy constructor for this? Thanks

Comment: @Milo: in this case, I would personally go for a non-copyable class. Declare the copy constructor and copy assignment operators as private and don't defined them. It will prevent the kind of mistake that occured here. You can read more on this idiom: http://dev-faqs.blogspot.com/2010/07/c-idioms-non-copyable.html

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Visual C++, the Windows debug heap overwrites freed memory with the `0xfe` memory pattern to help you to debug memory issues.

You've freed something and either (a) you are trying to access that thing or (b) you are trying to free that thing again.

Since your class manually manages resources, and since you don't show the copy constructor and copy assignment operator implementations, make sure you are following the [rule of three](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_%28C%2B%2B_programming%29).

Answer (score 1):

Is Allegro being shut down in `main`? If so, then when the global destructs *after* `main`, I suspect `al_destroy_bitmap` should fail.

And like James says, you're breaking the rule of three; this probably plays a role. This `bitmap = AguiBitmap("somepath");` will call `al_destroy_bitmap(nativeBitmapPtr);` when the temporary dies; does this leave `bitmap` with a bad pointer?

---

Aside from the question, why do you have a `char*` overload of the constructor? That's nasty. The C-style cast is acting like a `const_cast`, that should be a hint something is wrong. `std::string` can initialize from literals anyway, so I'm not sure why you even have two. Just have one, and don't cast any const's away.